# Не получается вывести информацию на страницу

Tags: php, html, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести кол.во строк в таблице, но не выводится, файл формата index.php
SQL запрос возвращает все как надо, база подключена.

```
<section class="target">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h2>Зарегистированно участников:</h2>
                <?php
                        include 'bd.php';

                        $results = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM register_user");
                        $arrays = mysql_fetch_array($results);

                        while ($arrays = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
                            echo ""."<p>".$results."</p>"."";
                        }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Запрос:     `SELECT  count(*)  FROM register_user` и он посчитает пользователей

Comment: Мне нужно вывести кол.во строк на страницу: https://imgur.com/a/MNbib

Comment: MySQL и так всё прекрасно считает, а вот вывести на страницу не выходит, почему то.

Comment: Не то выводите выведите $arrays[0], используйте var_dump[$arrays] и увидите содержание массива